# What is the Hood size and UV filter size for NIKKOR 18-55 mm and NIKKOR 70-300 mm?

Tags: nikon, dslr, filters, lens-hood, filter-diameter

Recently I have purchased a Nikon D3400 having two lenses. They are;

1. **AF-P DX NIKKOR 18-55 mm f/3.5 - 5.6G VR** and
2. **AF-P DX NIKKOR 70-300 mm f/4.5 - 6.3G ED VR**

I would like to purchase a **Hood** and **UV filter** for each. I have tried `Axcess 67mm YC Clear View UV-HD Lens UV Filter` and `Axcess 52mm YC Clear View UV-HD Lens UV Filter`, but they are not correctly fitting into lens. One (52mm) is smaller and the other (67mm) is larger. Somebody kindly tell me the UV filter and Hood size for both lenses?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Inside the cap, its written 55mm (1st lens) and 58mm (2nd lens)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the measurements are usualy inside lens cap

Comment: its written 55mm and 58mm

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ That's the size of the front element.  You need filters that match that size.